# Django or conventional PHP?

Tags: php, python, django, web

Currently, I am the president and the code head of my school's IT club. The thing is, I made a website for club (which is yet to be surfaced online). I used basic HTML, CSS, JS and PHP. For now, I got the website running on Apache localhost with phpmyadmin. The dilemma I'm facing is, should I use Django instead? For now, I can code really well in Python, but have no experience in Django. The specifications of the website are:

- The website has a registration page using which school admins can register students for the IT fest that we are organizing.
- The website has an 'Events' page where all the events we have conducted or will conduct will be displayed. This info will be stored and retrieved from the database. For now I got my Events page to work by implementing a PHP loop for creating divs.
- The homepage has some good looking CSS and JS scroll animations.

This definitely is a small scale website (don't get me wrong, complete website has not been described above). The trouble is, no one seems to take interest in coding or event organizing or anything that our group stands for. I have started this group in hopes of creating an interest in juniors. And the biggest problem is, I will pass out from the school in 4 months. So should I create my website in Django to provide learning opportunity to students, or should I keep it the way it is, so as to make it easier for them to manage?
P.S. - No guy at my school possesses even a teeny tiny bit of knowledge on web dev.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting or VPS? I would say give Django a try and see how it goes.

Comment: I'll be hosting the site on GoDaddy

Answer (score 0):

from the description I find that your website has very less to do with backend so python or PHP part would be less. moreover For such a website overhead for learning Django will be more.you should continue to use PHP. On the other side if you use Django as its a framework it will help you keep your work managed. as as you say you are interested in python you will fly !

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNQxxpM1yOs&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeA05ZouE4OzDYLHY-XH-Nd

This is a link to a easy an intuitive Django tutorial you may want to look at before deciding.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! What I've decided is, that for now I'll keep the PHP server code because we have an event a month later, and we'll need the website for registrations. After that, I'll learn Django (considering that it'll be easy due to my knowledge in python) and change the website.